# add_error(fieldname, ...) in Django Rest Framework (DRF)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I have a model serializer like this:

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('myfield', 'otherfield')
```

I need to check a cross-field condition, say, `x.myfield > x.otherfield`.
(There are actually several `otherfields` and several conditions.)

I need detailed and easy-to-grasp human-readable error messages.
I currently generate them (actually only the first) in `MySerializer.validate()` via `raise ValidationError(message)`, but then the message comes under the `non-field-errors` key, which is ugly and difficult for the users. It would be much nicer to attach it to `myfield`.

In Django forms, I would use `add_error('myfield', ...)`, but I
[could not find a similar thing](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation) in rest framework.
What is a suitable idiom here?

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple!

```
raise ValidationError(dict(myfield=[message]))
```

This way, one can mention multiple fields overall and can have multiple messages per field.

#### Where to find it

As of 2021-05, the respective information comes under
[Overriding serialization and deserialization behavior](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior) in the documentation, not under "Validation" as one might expect.

(Why do I so often have to write a near-complete stackoverflow post before I finally find what I'm looking for in the documentation? I don't know. Hope it helps others now.)